# Haskell: Maximum/minimum function

Tags: haskell

Is there a function in Haskell like say:

```
max_of_type :: (Num a) => a
```

So:

```
max_of_type :: Int == 2 ^ 31 - 1 // for example, implementation dependent
```

Comment: Note that this is not a function; it's just a value, albeit defined by typeclass instances.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's called `maxBound`.

There is also `minBound`. They are both part of the `Bounded` type class.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, but I can't yet. Found the answer just after posting.

Answer (score 1):

Oops, it's just `maxBound` and `minBound`.